# SPException error codes and meanings (refreshing form request digest via SharePoint REST services)

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Where can I find a list of error codes and their meanings for SharePoint exceptions?  I can't find any list of any kind online, just specific cases here and there.

My specific need arises out of the following scenario:

- SharePoint 2013 REST services
- Refresh form request digest

I have discovered that if my form request digest has timed out, I will receive:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "-2130575252, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "value": "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."
    }
}
```

That's great, I can just look for error code -2130575252, refresh my request digest and try it again, right?  Well, maybe ... I'm left wondering in what other scenario might this error code be used?  What other error codes may indicate a similar situation?  With a little error code documentation I could feel more confident that this is the one and only error that a stale request digest will produce.  Alas, where's the documentation?

Comment: Some are documented on the methods that can raise them but I can't find a comprehensive list.  Here's an example.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcollection.add.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I've yet to find a comprehensive list either, not was there any information about error codes discussed at SPC2014 that I recall.

However, you're not likely to need a reference.  Aside from this one crazy code, SP will basically provide good error descriptions into the error object (e.g.: "Column User_x0020_Name does not exist."

In this case, I just catch the exception, verify the exception code (parse response with JSON.parse), refresh the page form digest token, then resubmit your AJAX request so the user doesn't have to intervene.

Updating a security token (default timeout is 30 minutes for on-prem):

`UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, _spFormDigestRefreshInterval);`

Comment: I don't think those are just any standard codes.  They look to be for the azure storage rest services, not SharePoint